# What is the difference between <- and "let" inside do blocks?

Tags: haskell, frege

I don't understand when do I have to use `let` and when do I have to use the `<-` binding.

Comment: Read more about what actually `let` means, and what actually `<-` does. And, probably, about the `do` notaion.

Answer (score 7):

`let` gives a name to the result of a function call.

`<-` binds the result of a monadic operation in the current monad to a name.

They're quite different. Use `let` for the results of functions outside the monad, i.e. normal pure functions. Use `<-` for anything monadic, as it "unwraps" the monad result and lets you get at the value inside it.

For example:

assume an IO function with the following signature

```
frobnicate :: String -> IO Bool
```

and a pure function

```
dothing :: Bool -> Bool
```

we can do this

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- frobnicate "Hello"
  let y = frobnicate "Hello"
  -- z <- dothing x
  let z = dothing x
  return ()
```

And we know that `x :: Bool` because the `Bool` has been extracted from the `IO` operation result for us (the operation runs, and the result is called `x` so we can use it later).

We also know that `y :: IO Bool` - the operation hasn't been run, it's the *potential* for an IO operation in the future. So the only useful thing we can do with `y` is run it later, bind the result and get at the `Bool` inside that way, but after a `let` that `Bool` doesn't even exist yet.

The third line is commented out because it won't compile - you can't do a monadic bind on an operation which is not in the relevant monad. `dothing` doesn't return an `IO` anything, so you can't bind it inside an `IO ()` function.

The fourth line is straightforward - `z` is made to be the result of `dothing x`, where `x` was the value unwrapped from running `frobnicate "Hello"` earlier.

All of this is just syntactic sugar for the 'real' monad operations underneath, so that expands (without the commented out part) to something like

```
main = frobnicate "Hello" >>= (\x -> let y = frobnicate "Hello"
                                         z = dothing x
                                      in return ())
```

The example of course makes no sense at all, but hopefully it illustrates where `let` and `<-` differ within `do` notation.

TL;DR: use `<-` for giving names to the results of monadic operations, `let` for giving names to everything else.

Answer (score 3):

`<-` is to `>>=` (`bind`) where `let` is to `fmap` in a `do` block.

Stealing an example from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation):

```
do x1 <- action1 x0
   x2 <- action2 x1
   action3 x1 x2

-- is equivalent to:
action1 x0 >>= \ x1 -> action2 x1 >>= \ x2 -> action3 x1 x2
```

`action1`, `action2` & `action3` all return some sort of monad, say:

```
action1 :: (Monad m) => a -> m b
action2 :: (Monad m) => b -> m c
action3 :: (Monad m) => b -> c -> m d
```

You can rewrite let bindings as such:

```
-- assume action1 & action3 are the same
-- but action2 is thus:
action2 :: b -> c

do
    x1 <- action1 x0
    let x2 = action2 x1
    action3 x1 x2

do
    x1 <- action1 x0
    x2 <- return & action2 x1
    action3 x1 x2

-- of course it doesn't make sense to call action2
-- an action anymore, it's just a pure function.
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example to visualize what `<-` does:

```
do
    a <- ['a'..'z']
    b <- [1..3]
    pure (a,b)
```

You can try this in the online REPL at [try.frege-lang.org](http://try.frege-lang.org/)
(You can enter this as a single line:

```
do { a <- ['a'..'z']; b <- [1..3]; pure (a,b) }
```